# Using a QTimer for a function? [Qt]

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to set a `QTimer` on a function that gets run in my program. I have the following code:

```
// Redirect Console output to a QTextEdit widget
new Q_DebugStream(std::cout, ui->TXT_C); 

// Run a class member function that outputs Items via cout and shows them in a QTextEdit widget
// I want to set up a QTimer like the animation below for this.
myClass p1;
p1.display("Item1\nItem2\nItem3", 200);

// show fading animation of a QTextEdit box after 1000 milliseconds
// this works and will occur AFTER the QDialog shows up no problem.
QGraphicsOpacityEffect *eff = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(this);
ui->TXT_C->setGraphicsEffect(eff);
QPropertyAnimation* a = new QPropertyAnimation(eff,"opacity");
a->setDuration(2000);
a->setStartValue(.75);
a->setEndValue(0);
a->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutCubic);
QTimer::singleShot(1000, a, SLOT(start()));
```

**myClass.cpp**

```
myClass::myClass()
{}

int myClass::display(std::string hello, int speed)
{
  int x=0;
  while ( hello[x] != '\0')
  {
    std::cout << hello[x];
    Sleep(speed);
    x++;
  };
    std::cout << "\n\nEnd of message..";
    return 0;
}
```

I would like to get the first part (`p1.display(...);`) to work just like the second animation where I set up a QTimer for it to show up after a set amount of time. How would I go about doing this?

Ideally, I would want something like:

`QTimer::singleShot(500, "p1.display("Item1\nItem2\nItem3", 200)", SLOT(start()));`

This code obviously doesn't makse sense and won't work, but it hopefully gets the point across for what I'd like to do.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Basic solution**

You can call a slot from the calling class (can't see what its called in your code) just like you do for the second animation (you have to add the slot function):

```
QTimer::singleShot(500, this, SLOT(slotToCallP1Display()));
```

Then add the slot function:

```
void whateverThisTopLevelClassIsCalled::slotToCallP1Display()
{
   myClass p1;
   p1.display("Item1\nItem2\nItem3", 200);
}
```

**qt 5.5 / c++11**

I believe you could do somthing like this (using lambda to create a functor):

```
myClass p1;
QTimer::singleShot(500, []() { p1.display("Item1\nItem2\nItem3", 200); } );
```

I have not tested this code, but I did something similar recently.

Comment: The lambda solution worked. I just needed to add [&p1] in the square brackets. Thank you!

Comment: @orbit Oh yah +1, I'm a bit crap with the lambda format, I don't use it much because its so ugly (imho).... but it has its uses! :)

Comment: Watch out for the lambda solution, you need to ensure that `p1` lives long enough.

Comment: If you are not playing with any concurrency (threads, posix signals, …), you can ensure that `p1` is alive by passing `p1` as the context: `QTimer::singleShot(500, &p1, lambda function)`. The context guarantees that your functor only gets called if it still exist.